# Running command as sudo user without a password within a script (.sh file)

Tags: linux, sudo

I am trying to create a script that will remove ***.pyc** files from a DJango/Python project.

these files look something as follows:

```
./backend/libmstr/vendors/migrations/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
./backend/libmstr/vendors/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
./backend/libmstr/vendors/__pycache__/models.cpython-36.pyc
./backend/libmstr/vendors/__pycache__/admin.cpython-36.pyc
```

The permissions are as follows:

```
ls -lart ./backend/libmstr/vendors/migrations/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 143 Dec 21 15:55 ./backend/libmstr/vendors/migrations/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
```

As one can see, the **group and user for such a file is root**.

Given that I am not running anything as root, I am unure of where they come from.

So, I have elected to remove them using a function. In order for the function to run with no problem, it has to be ran under "sudo"

I created the file : **/home/dockerdj/remove_pyc_files.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \; -print
```

The file (above) was created on the user account : **dockerdj**  I have also given the user **sudo privileges**. I have also added the following to the `.bashrc` file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/dockcclubdjango
```

I have also added the following in `/etc/sudoers` by following this :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos

```
dockerdj ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/dockerdj/remove_pyc_files.sh
```

Even after doing the operations above, when running `remove_pyc_files.sh`, I am still asked for a password.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is mandatory that the system asks you for the user's password to confirm that this is the user, you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

PASSWORD='password or something';
echo -n -e '${PASSWORD}' | sudo -S find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \; -print
```

> This way the script will not ask you for the password, another thing you can do is have the password in hexadecimal and make a join with **'\\x'**